# PostgreSQL poor performance in LEFT JOIN + IS NOT DISTINCT FROM

Tags: postgresql

I'm dealing with JOIN two tables as follows:

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM (SELECT * FROM lines_stats_process limit 800) lsp
    LEFT JOIN lines l ON 

    (lsp.id_data_source_connection = l.id_data_source_connection) AND 
    (lsp.id_sys_country IS NOT DISTINCT FROM l.id_sys_country) AND
    (lsp.advertiser_name IS NOT DISTINCT FROM l.advertiser_name) AND 
    (lsp.size_name IS NOT DISTINCT FROM l.size_name) AND 
    (lsp.dsp IS NOT DISTINCT FROM l.dsp) AND 

    (lsp.id_advertiser IS NOT DISTINCT FROM l.id_advertiser) AND 
    (lsp.id_placement IS NOT DISTINCT FROM l.id_placement) AND
    (lsp.id_site IS NOT DISTINCT FROM l.id_site) AND
    (lsp.id_campaign IS NOT DISTINCT FROM l.id_campaign) 
    ) test;
```

NOTE: I'm using count and limit 800 just for testing purposes. Without limit, the query never ends to execute.

My DDL:

```
    CREATE TABLE public.lines
    (
      id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('lines_seq'::regclass),
      id_account integer NOT NULL,
      id_data_source integer NOT NULL,
      id_data_source_connection integer NOT NULL,
      id_client integer,
      id_advertiser bigint,
      advertiser_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      id_campaign bigint,
      campaign_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      id_group bigint,
      group_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      id_ad bigint,
      ad_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      id_site bigint,
      site_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      id_placement bigint,
      placement_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      id_format bigint,
      format_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      id_size bigint,
      size_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      created_at timestamp(0) without time zone DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date,
      updated_at timestamp(0) without time zone DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date,
      id_ds_advertiser integer,
      id_ds_campaign integer,
      id_ds_group integer,
      id_ds_ad integer,
      id_ds_site integer,
      id_ds_placement integer,
      id_ds_format integer,
      id_publisher integer,
      id_country integer,
      dsp character varying(45) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      country_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
      id_ds_country integer,
      id_sys_country integer,
      CONSTRAINT lines_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT lines_id_check CHECK (id > 0)
    )
    WITH (
      OIDS=FALSE
    );
    ALTER TABLE public.lines
      OWNER TO postgres;
    GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.lines TO postgres;

    -- Index: public.data_source_connection_lines

    -- DROP INDEX public.data_source_connection_lines;

    CREATE INDEX data_source_connection_lines
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (id_data_source_connection);

    -- Index: public.id_data_source_connection211

    -- DROP INDEX public.id_data_source_connection211;

    CREATE INDEX id_data_source_connection211
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (id_data_source_connection);

    -- Index: public.lines_advertiser_name

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_advertiser_name;

    CREATE INDEX lines_advertiser_name
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (advertiser_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

    -- Index: public.lines_countries

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_countries;

    CREATE INDEX lines_countries
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (id_country);

    -- Index: public.lines_dsp

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_dsp;

    CREATE INDEX lines_dsp
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (dsp COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

    -- Index: public.lines_id_advertiser

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_id_advertiser;

    CREATE INDEX lines_id_advertiser
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (id_advertiser);

    -- Index: public.lines_id_campaign

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_id_campaign;

    CREATE INDEX lines_id_campaign
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (id_campaign);

    -- Index: public.lines_id_data_source_connection

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_id_data_source_connection;

    CREATE INDEX lines_id_data_source_connection
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (id_data_source_connection);

    -- Index: public.lines_id_placement

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_id_placement;

    CREATE INDEX lines_id_placement
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (id_placement);

    -- Index: public.lines_id_site

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_id_site;

    CREATE INDEX lines_id_site
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (id_site);

    -- Index: public.lines_lsp

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_lsp;

    CREATE INDEX lines_lsp
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (id_data_source_connection, advertiser_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", size_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", dsp COLLATE pg_catalog."default", id_advertiser, id_placement, id_site, id_campaign, id_sys_country);

    -- Index: public.lines_lsp2

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_lsp2;

    CREATE INDEX lines_lsp2
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (id_data_source_connection, id_country, advertiser_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", size_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", dsp COLLATE pg_catalog."default", id_advertiser, id_placement, id_site, id_campaign);

    -- Index: public.lines_size_name

    -- DROP INDEX public.lines_size_name;

    CREATE INDEX lines_size_name
      ON public.lines
      USING btree
      (size_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default");











-- Table: public.lines_stats_process

-- DROP TABLE public.lines_stats_process;

CREATE TABLE public.lines_stats_process
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('lines_stats_process_seq'::regclass),
  id_line integer,
  id_line_stat integer,
  id_account integer NOT NULL,
  id_data_source integer NOT NULL,
  id_data_source_connection integer NOT NULL,
  id_client integer,
  id_advertiser bigint,
  advertiser_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  id_campaign bigint,
  campaign_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  id_group bigint,
  group_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  id_ad bigint,
  ad_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  id_site bigint,
  site_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  id_placement bigint,
  placement_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  id_format bigint,
  format_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  id_size bigint,
  size_name character varying(200) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  created_at timestamp(0) without time zone DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date,
  updated_at timestamp(0) without time zone DEFAULT ('now'::text)::date,
  id_ds_advertiser integer,
  id_ds_campaign integer,
  id_ds_group integer,
  id_ds_ad integer,
  id_ds_site integer,
  id_ds_placement integer,
  id_ds_format integer,
  id_publisher integer,
  id_country integer,
  dsp character varying(45) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  date date NOT NULL,
  country_name character varying(50) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  id_sys_country integer,
  id_ds_country integer,
  budget numeric(10,2) DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
  bid numeric(10,2) DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
  CONSTRAINT lines_stats_process_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT lines_stats_process_id_check CHECK (id > 0)
)
WITH (
  FILLFACTOR=70, 
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.lines_stats_process
  OWNER TO postgres;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE public.lines_stats_process TO postgres;

-- Index: public.data_source_connection_lsp

-- DROP INDEX public.data_source_connection_lsp;

CREATE INDEX data_source_connection_lsp
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (id_data_source_connection);

-- Index: public.id_data_source_connection21

-- DROP INDEX public.id_data_source_connection21;

CREATE INDEX id_data_source_connection21
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (id_data_source_connection);

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_advertiser_name

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_advertiser_name;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_advertiser_name
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (advertiser_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_countries

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_countries;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_countries
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (id_sys_country);

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_dsp

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_dsp;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_dsp
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (dsp COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_id_advertiser

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_id_advertiser;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_id_advertiser
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (id_advertiser);

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_id_campaign

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_id_campaign;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_id_campaign
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (id_campaign);

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_id_data_source_connection

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_id_data_source_connection;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_id_data_source_connection
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (id_data_source_connection);

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_id_placement

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_id_placement;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_id_placement
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (id_placement);

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_id_site

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_id_site;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_id_site
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (id_site);

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_lsp

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_lsp;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_lsp
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (id_data_source_connection, advertiser_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", size_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", dsp COLLATE pg_catalog."default", id_advertiser, id_placement, id_site, id_campaign, id_sys_country);

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_lsp2

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_lsp2;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_lsp2
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (id_data_source_connection, id_sys_country, advertiser_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", size_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default", dsp COLLATE pg_catalog."default", id_advertiser, id_placement, id_site, id_campaign);

-- Index: public.lines_stats_process_size_name

-- DROP INDEX public.lines_stats_process_size_name;

CREATE INDEX lines_stats_process_size_name
  ON public.lines_stats_process
  USING btree
  (size_name COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

This is the [EXPLAIN ANALYZE](http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/plan_1480261628928)

The lines_stats_process has 60K rows. I'm limiting it to 800 in order to have a reasonable execution time.

I've made several test, I've disabled the following options:

```
SET enable_nestloop =off;
SET enable_material = off;
SET enable_seqscan = off;
```

But never gets a better performance.

The only change that has some effect was to replace `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` for `=`. After change that, the execution takes less than a second.
Of course, that operator isn't correct for my logic, so I need to use `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` because I need null-safe comparison.
After made all the replaces, I started to put back `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` one by one. When I put back the last `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` the query takes too long to execute.

I put the `=` in any other condition with the same effect. With 8 `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` takes too long. With 7 `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` it executes with less than a second.

Sorry for my english, is not my native language.

Comment: The link to the plan is not working (at least for me)

Comment: `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` can not use an index, see e.g. the discussion on the mailing list: http://postgresql.nabble.com/How-to-hint-2-coulms-IS-NOT-DISTINCT-FROM-each-other-td5928175.html the recommendation there is to rewrite that to `((a IS NULL AND b IS NULL) OR (a = b))` instead of `a is not distinct from b` - for that Postgres could use an index

Comment: Note: all your fields *look like* foreign keys into separate domains ("dimensions") Are they? what is their cardinality? Are your two tables *fact tables* ?

Comment: Why do you have **5** indexes on `id_data_source_connection`? That is a total waste of space and time.

Comment: @Andreas that's a test, I've tested with several index combinations.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Your solution is the best, now it takes only 43 seconds to execute query! But lines_stats_process has 59651 rows and the result of JOIN return 63376 rows. Why are some records duplicated?

Comment: They are not duplicated; they appear twice in the `lines` table (probably), and you asked for them.

Comment: Dead link @a_horse_with_no_name, any idea if this is still the case? It would verify the research I've been doing into my system. I've seen the same link in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is not indexable*, which leads to sequential scans, which becomes terribly slow horribly fast.

The short answer to your problem is: don't use `NULL` the way you're using it now. Joining on equality of NULL values is A Bad Idea™;

The somewhat longer answer is: You should think of `NULL`, semantically, as value "non-existent", so the implication is that it does not carry meaning other than the absence of meaning.

However, if you replace all `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` with equality plus null check, you should be fine as well, meaning `a IS DISTINCT FROM b` should be written as `(a=b OR (a IS NULL AND b IS NULL))`.

*) As a final aside, it appears an [implementation detail](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/6FC83909-5DB1-420F-9191-DBE533A3CEDE@excoventures.com) that `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM` is not indexable. I'm not sure about the details, but someone might be able to elaborate.